# Using tomcat server to query multiple Active Directories

Tags: tomcat, active-directory, tomcat6, radius

I have a webapp deployed on tomcat server , I am using LDAP for authentication and connect to a local AD server.

No i have a requirement where there are multiple users who have to access the same app but are located on more than one AD. Now i am struggling to find how to connect my tomcat to multiple AD serves.

I thought RADIUS might be an option, but again I cant find a sutiable configuration required for the RADIUS server in the tomcat config.

Will appreciate any help?

Answer (score 0):

You are wasting your time! Use SPNEGO with Active Directory and your are able to authenticate from ANY domain as long as your home domain has a trust. LDAP bind is soo...

Comment: Not sure if I can add SPNEGO to my enrionment. To be honest I didnt know about SPNEGO till now. Looking for something which can be achieved by using RADIUS or some tomcat configuartion or may a 3rd part tool

Comment: No need to use RADIUS. SPNEGO **will** do. What is your Tomcat version?

Comment: OK, if you run Java 6 you could use a my custom component for Tomcat 6.

Comment: Thanks Michael looks like we are progressing but you would need to eloborate for me please

Comment: I have written a [custom component](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tomcatspnegoad/?source=directory) for Tomcat which performs SPNEGO auth and then look ups the user in the AD and retrieves the groups from. The code is production quality but documention is incomplete but JavaDoc is fine.

Comment: So is this something which can be shared?

Comment: Yes, this is licensed under ASLv2.